# Android: Invalid Credentials on access token when updated from PlusClient to GoogleApiClient

Tags: android, google-api

I was successfully getting an access token via PlusClient and GoogleAuthUtil to query googleapis from backend

my working code was:

```
 mPlusClient =
            new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this).setScopes( Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN,Scopes.PLUS_ME , Scopes.PROFILE, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email").build();
```

....

```
String accessToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(this, mPlusClient.getAccountName(), "oauth2:" + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN );
```

passed accessToken to backend so it can call Google like:

```
GET: https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=accessToken
```

As PlusClient is now deprecated and I need GoogleMaps V2 I have migrated the code using GoogleApiClient.

The problem is that the token received from GoogleAuthUtil.getToken after upgrading to GoogleApiClient gets "invalid credentials"

Seems that I'm missing something but I don't know what

Thank you in advance.